# Remove format of input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an input to an amount. I put a JS code to autofill with dots (thousands) and to add $ at the begin (Ex: $12.000). The data is send to a SOAP. So what I need now are the numbers without $ and dots. ¿Any suggestion?

JS CODE

```
function autofill(input){
    aux = input.value.replace('$','');
    var num = aux.replace(/\./g,'');
    if(!isNaN(num)){
        num = num.toString().split('').reverse().join('').replace(/(?=\d*\.?)(\d{3})/g,'$1.');
        num = num.split('').reverse().join('').replace(/^[\.]/,'');            
        input.value = '$'+num;
    }else{             
        input.value = '$'+input.value.replace(/[^\d\.]*/g,'');
}
```

HTML Input

```
<input id="vida_ingreso" onkeyup="autofill(this)" type="text">
```

Comment: When I read your question I read it as: "I need an underlying object associated with the input that has a getter and a setter defined". That would be my suggestion. [Referrence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get)

Comment: Why not just store the original input string on a data attribute for the element? Assuming that is the value you want

Comment: My idea is to remove the format using js too but idk how do it. Ty bro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.replace()`

```
var str = "$12.000";
var fStr = str.replace("$","").replace(".000","");
```

Comment: I took your logic and it was helpful to use replace and then other replace in the same line. This helped me. TY.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the dot for thousands, you can just remove the extra characters and use parseInt.

```
function unfill(input){
    aux = input.value.replace('$','');
    var num = aux.replace(/\./g,'');
    return parseInt(num, 10);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace all instances of `$` and `.`:

```
var input = document.getElementById('vida_ingreso');
var repl = input.value.replace(/\$|\./g, '');
alert(repl);
```

Example here: http://jsbin.com/milugu/1/edit?js,output

**Edit:**
If you need the value as a number, use:

```
var num = Number(repl);
```

http://jsbin.com/milugu/2/edit

Comment: it could be a possibility, ty!